# keep command window open after running bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch

i have a bat file that has the following it:

```
sm start "Schedule"
```

this code runs but the command window closes immediately

what can i put inside the bat file to keep the window open?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just put the command `pause` in the batch file at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can run it with `cmd /k mybatfile.bat` instead of `cmd mybatfile.bat`. Very useful if you can't edit the file or want to invoke a quick command from `Run`. F.e.: `cmd /k ipconfig`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "sm" or "Schedule" are.  But if "start" is cmd.exe's integrated start command, you may be looking for:

```
sm start /wait "Schedule"
```